# Enzyme / Jest spies not called onClick

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test an event handler with Enzyme / Jest for a react component, however my spy function is never called...

My component has a div with an id and I am using that to find the dom elem

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Top
                {...this.props}
            />
            <div 
                id = 'keyboard_clickable'
                onClick = {this._handleClick}
                style= {styles.main}>
                {this._showKeyBoard()}
            </div>
            <input onChange = {() => {}}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My test

```
describe('onclick function is called ...', () => {
  it.only('spyOn', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn()

    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Keyboard 
      _getData      = { () => {} }
      _erase        = { () => {} }
      _get_letters  = { () => {} }
      _createWord   = { () => {} }
      _modeSwitch   = { () => {} }
      onClick       = { spy      }
      />
    )

    wrapper.find('#keyboard_clickable').simulate('click', {
      target:{
        parentElement:{ id: 5 },
        id:6
        }
    })
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
})
```

my HandleClick

```
_handleClick = e => {
    let parent = e.target.parentElement;
    if(e.target.id || (!isNaN(parent.id) && parent.id > 0) ) {
        this.props._getData(e.target.id || e.target.parentElement.id)
        this.setState({status:'ok'})
    }else{
        this.setState({status:'Use numbers between 2 and 9'},()=>{
            return alert(this.state.status)
        })

    }
}
```

Test output

```
Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

Comment: Could you please show what Keyboard._handleClick does? I suspect it might not be calling Keyboard.props.onClick.

Comment: Yeah is not calling Keyboard.props._handleClick, the method is Keyboard._handleClick

Comment: Please add it to your original post, it is barely readable here

Comment: Your _handleClick method never calls an onClick props. What you could test instead is that the state is correctly changed and that the _getData props get called

Answer (score 3):

To test that your event handler is called, you'll have to replace the event handler with a mock function. One way to do that is to extend your component class:

```
class TestKeyboard extends Keyboard {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._handleClick = this.props._handleClick
  }
}

describe('onclick function is called ...', () => {
  it.only('spyOn', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn()

    const wrapper = shallow(
      <TestKeyboard 
      _getData      = { () => {} }
      _erase        = { () => {} }
      _get_letters  = { () => {} }
      _createWord   = { () => {} }
      _modeSwitch   = { () => {} }
      _handleClick  = { spy      }
      />
    )

    wrapper.find('#keyboard_clickable').simulate('click', {
      target:{
        parentElement:{ id: 5 },
        id:6
        }
    })
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
})
```

The prop `_handleClick` replaces Keyboard._handleClick and is therefore called when `onClick` fires in the clicked element.

### Alternatively, jest.spyOn

In case you need to let the event handler execute **and** test what it was called with, you can use `jest.spyOn`. I find this method more complex, but it is more flexible.

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

describe('onclick function is called ...', () => {
  it.only('spyOn', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Keyboard 
      _getData      = { () => {} }
      _erase        = { () => {} }
      _get_letters  = { () => {} }
      _createWord   = { () => {} }
      _modeSwitch   = { () => {} }
      />
    )

    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), '_handleClick')
    wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()

    wrapper.find('#keyboard_clickable').simulate('click', {
      target:{
        parentElement:{ id: 5 },
        id:6
        }
    })
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
})
```

Note that this will fail when using shallow rendering so you'll have to use enzyme.mount instead.

Comment: Thanks  that indeed passes the test!

Comment: I was missing wrapper.instance().forceUpdate(), thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simulating a click with enzyme in shallow render does work, but only if I forceUpdate(), like in Jemi's solution.

example:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<VehicleDamage handleSubmit={mockFunction} onPrevClick={mockFunction} />);
});

it('handlePrevClick is called on click', function() {
    const spyHandlePrevClick = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handlePrevClick');
    wrapper.instance().forceUpdate(); // I assume required to assign mocked function

    let buttonContainer = wrapper.find('ButtonContainer').dive();
    let button = buttonContainer.find('Button').at(0);

    button.simulate('click', {
        preventDefault: () => jest.fn()
    });

    expect(spyHandlePrevClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```